# SQL triggers cause errors

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1054

Let's create a `TestParent` table which caches the total value of the `num` column in a `TestChild` table, and insert some rows.

```
CREATE TABLE TestParent (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
total INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

CREATE TABLE TestChild (
parent_id INT NOT NULL,
num INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO TestParent (id) VALUES (123);
INSERT INTO TestChild (parent_id, num) VALUES (123, 1);

CREATE PROCEDURE Sync (IN parent INT)
    UPDATE TestParent SET total = (
        SELECT SUM(num) FROM TestChild WHERE parent_id=parent)
    WHERE id=parent;

CALL Sync (123);
```

So far, so good. Now, I want `Sync` to be called automatically...

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestInsert
AFTER INSERT ON TestChild
FOR EACH ROW CALL Sync (parent_id);
```

This also works. Now,

```
INSERT INTO TestChild (parent_id, num) VALUES (123, 1);
```

gives

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'parent_id' in 'field list'
```

The insert has happened, but the stored procedure hasn't been called. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `NEW.parent_id` to refer to a value that just got inserted

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestInsert
AFTER INSERT ON TestChild
FOR EACH ROW CALL Sync (NEW.parent_id);
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. Any idea why id can't/doesn't catch this sort of error when the trigger is created?

Comment: Because this is freeware database engine with a lot of disadvantages like this.

Comment: 1. MySQL is not freeware - it's GPL licensed. 2. It's because it is not a syntax error. Upon creation MySQL has no way of knowing in what contex the trigger will be executed. There is a possobility (although I can't come up with any at that time), where trigger defined like you did would make sense.